# cURL JSON Data Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, cmd

I have a Problem with this code:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.send([
    { id: 1, title: 'foo' }
]);
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
res.send({
        data: req.body
    })
    console.log("Geht");
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log('Server listening on port 3000.');
});
```

If I try to use "curl -X POST -d '{"user":"jane.doe"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:3000/" for example, I always get the following error:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse ()
at parse (C:\Programmieren\node test\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
at C:\Programmieren\node test\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
at invokeCallback (C:\Programmieren\node test\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
at done (C:\Programmieren\node test\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Programmieren\node test\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)

Can somebody tell me a solution to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For windows users, it worked with escaping the `"` character.

```
curl -X POST -d "{\"user\":\"jane.doe\"}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:3000/
```